# DOMDocument, get images AFTER first <h1>

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am trying to get all `<img>` tags after the first `<h1>` tag, but I can't quite figure how.

Currently I am able to get all `<img>` tags from a page using this code:

```
$html = file_get_contents($this->url);

$this->doc = new DOMDocument();
@$this->doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $this->doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    array_push($this->images, $tag->getAttribute('src'));
}
```

How can I make it do this **after** the first `<h1>` tag?

Comment: Are all the images on the same level in hierarchy and on the same level as the h1 or are they in different levels?

Comment: They will be on different levels

Comment: So, could you please add some information of the structure of the documents.

Comment: The only criteria is, the images are **after** the first <h1> tag. There is no structure, it needs to work on all pages.

Comment: The images could appear on any hierarchy layer, even higher than the h1, or simply besides it or in another element besides the h1?

Answer (score 0):

For php get a dom parser.
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_traverse

Find the h1 tag then use traverse the siblings searching for the img tags.

$es = $html->find( 'h1' )

```
foreach($es->next_sibling() as $sibling) 
{
       foreach($sibling->find( 'img' ) as $img ) 
       {
             // do something...
       }
}
```

Comment: But this does not work if they are in different hierarchy levels.

Comment: And this would not even work if they are totally spread along the hierarchy.

Comment: Your last edit is okay if the images are inside the same element as the h1. But if they are in a completely other element, your code will not find them. The author of the question did not answer if we are allowed to do this assumption. Until now he says they may appear in any other element and then this does not work.

Comment: Ya. If he has control over the source then it would be best to put all the images inside a containing div.

Comment: There you are absolutely right and therefore I asked about the structure of the document. But he said it is completely free and therefore I see only traversing the whole tree. The second problem is that the tree does not tell anything about the positioning of the elements. It therefore can happen that the first h1 in three is the footer of the site.